# How to change the install path of my Linux Source tree?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, make

I was trying to bring up my custom kernel. I did the following :

```
$ make menuconfig && make modules && make modules_install && make install
```

I would like to change the install PATH. How can i do that?

I tried doing

```
$ export INSTALL_PATH=<my custom path>
```

But then it is only creating `vmlinux.bin` (it is not creating the ramdisk image!)

But if I don't do that, `make install` will automatically create the ramdisk image in the default `/boot` folder.

How can i change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, I found where is that **install path**.

It is inside `/sbin`. The script file name is `installkernel`.

Just need to make a couple of changes in there and i could change the default install path of my Linux source(which was /boot).

Comment: And you can use "make install INSTALLKERNEL=XXX" to use a custom script as mentioned under `Documentation/kbuild`.

Answer (score 0):

You use a separate tool to create an initrd image.
Most distros use a command called `mkinitrd`, but Fedora has a tool called `dracut` that is supposed to replace `mkinitrd`.

Comment: but i would like to know from where is it getting the __install path__?